# Stop ssh key from being added automatically

Tags: ssh

My output for `ssh-add -l` is showing a bunch of keys right after boot.

I'd like for this not to be the case. Instead I'd like to have to add each one manually when I need it.

Removing the keys can be done with `-d` or `-D`, but how do you stop this behavior of automatic adding?

Comment: This doesn't sounds like the default behavior to me. I would think that some startup is adding the keys you see. Are there any `ssh-add` statements in your shell startup files(s)?

Comment: @user1794469 Don't know where to look for that. Also, running `ssh-add -D` seems to have no effect.